# UIView not resizing within UITableViewCell on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a UIView on every UITableViewCell.. This UIView has a event for touch to make it grow in height.

When user taps on this UIView the grow animation works fine, and then i mark a flag to indicate that this cell have a bigger UIView.

But when i need recycle that cell and make her bigger automatically the UIView won't grows when the UITableView displays the cell again. If i change the backgroundColor it displays the change, but don't work if i change their frame height.

A sample code:

**Custom UIViewController - UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([_dataSource count] > 0)
    {
        Model *model = [_dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        ModelCellView *cell = [model getViewFor: tableView];
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

**My Model with data**

```
- (ModelCellView*)getViewFor:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ModelCell";
    ModelCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[ModelCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    //Lots of code

    // Reset actionbar (UIView) to specific size
    [cell.actionBar resetToState: _actionBarOpened];

    //Lots of code

    return cell;
}
```

**My custom UIView class (ActionBar) inside custom UITableViewCell**

```
- (void)resetToState:(BOOL)opened;
{
    if(opened)
    {
        _closed = NO;
        //[self open]; //tried to change de frame height here, but dont work too.
    }
    else
    {
        _closed = YES;
        //[self close];  //tried to change de frame height here, but dont work too.
    }

    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    if(!_closed)
    {
        // This dont work
        int sizeToGrow = 60;
        [self setFrame: CGRectMake(
                                    _defaultPosition.x, 
                                    _defaultPosition.y - sizeToGrow, 
                                    _defaultSize.width, 
                                    _defaultSize.height + sizeToGrow)];

        // This work
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        // This work
        [_saveButton setFrame: CGRectMake(
                                            _saveButton.frame.origin.x, 
                                            INSIDE_VIEW_Y_POSITION, 
                                            _saveButton.frame.size.width, 
                                            _saveButton.frame.size.height)];

        // This work
        [_deleteButton setFrame: CGRectMake(
                                            _deleteButton.frame.origin.x, 
                                            INSIDE_VIEW_Y_POSITION, 
                                            _deleteButton.frame.size.width, 
                                            _deleteButton.frame.size.height)];
    }
    else
    {
        // This dont work
        [self setFrame: CGRectMake(
                                    _defaultPosition.x, 
                                    _defaultPosition.y, 
                                    _defaultSize.width, 
                                    _defaultSize.height)];

        // This work
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        // This work
        [_saveButton setFrame: CGRectMake(
                                            _saveButton.frame.origin.x, 
                                            OUTSIDE_VIEW_Y_POSITION, 
                                            _saveButton.frame.size.width, 
                                            _saveButton.frame.size.height)];

        // This work
        [_deleteButton setFrame: CGRectMake(
                                            _deleteButton.frame.origin.x, 
                                            OUTSIDE_VIEW_Y_POSITION, 
                                            _deleteButton.frame.size.width, 
                                            _deleteButton.frame.size.height)];
    }

    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: where did you call `layoutsubviews` method?

Comment: [self setNeedsLayout]; force UIView to call layoutsubviews. But i have tried to make changes on frame directly on resetToState but same problem occur.